How to delete all lines AFTER and INCLUDING a certain string?
I have a need to delete all lines in a csv AFTER and INCLUDING a certain string.  The string is as follows :

S_Channel_Alt_View


The file should then look like this

I've tried to set something up using Compare-Object but unable to get it to work.
Thank you!

How do you get those values? From an already existing CSV? Could you post the code you wrote, so we can see if it only needs some fix or else?

It's an export file from an application, so the lines can change each time it's exported.
$lines = Get-Content .\Custom2.csv
$rem = @()
@("Channel_Alt_View") | Foreach {
$rem += $lines[(($lines | Select-String -Pattern "$").LineNumber)..(($lines | Select-String -Pattern "$").LineNumber+400)]
}
Compare-Object $lines $rem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject | Set-Content .\New.csv

I used 400 as the ending because the file will never have that amount. So figured it was a good catch all number

plese update your original post, do not write the relevant code in comments.

it's a simple matter of loading the original CSV then looping through it and stop once you find the wanted value
$CsvContent = Import-Csv -Path 'c:\path\to\your\csv.csv'
$ColumnName = 'Custom2'
$FilterValue = 'S_Channel_Alt_View'

$FilteredContent = foreach ($Line in $CsvContent) {
    $Line
    if ($Line.$ColumnName -like $FilterValue ) { break }
}
$FilteredContent | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\path\to\your\csv_2.csv'


That worked like a charm, thank you.

mind you: this script presume the stuff you want is ALWAYS before the breaking line(breaking line included)
